# How do I use Opengl 3.2?

Tags: opengl

My computer is using OpenGL 3.1 and I want to develop in OpenGL 3.2 but I don't know how.
Thanks in advance all help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Your question is too broad to answer.  It's also unsuited to this particular site; see the [faq] (especially the part about "could an entire book be written to answer your question").  You should search the wider internet for a tutorial, because you won't find what you need in this site's Q&A format.

Comment: I don't think this question merits closure.  It seems more as a result of a common enough misconception about what OpenGL actually *is* rather than an "entire book" case, and as such deserves to stay open and be answered, if for no other reason than to provide a reference for correcting that misconception.

Comment: Older Intel GPUs are limited to 3.1 as are the Open Source Mesa drivers currently.

Comment: @mh01 Yeah, you might be right.  I think there's some reasonable question in there.

Comment: @mh01: What misconception? The question is nothing as it currently stands. Stop trying to answer the question you *think* is being asked and answer the *actual question*. If the OP wants to fix the question to be reasonable, fine. But until then, it should be closed.

Comment: @NicolBolas - you missed the part of my post where I said "seems".

Answer (score 3):

Your computer needs to have a graphics card and driver that supports a version of OpenGL before you can test it on your machine. Since OpenGL is a specification, you could technically write and compile code that uses OpenGL features that are not supported on your system, but you're not going to have a way to see if it works.

The first thing that you should do is check for graphics card driver updates. Often times, it's just the drivers that need to be updated. The next thing to do is see if the features from OpenGL 3.2 you want are available as extensions. If so, then just use the extensions and you're set.

Worst case scenario, you upgrade your graphics card (assuming you're working on a desktop) and get OpenGL 4.3+ as well. You could also try testing the parts of your code that rely on 3.2 features on a friend's machine that has support.